# How can I use switch instead of multiple if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I was wondering if it is possible to rewrite multiple `if` statements into a `switch`.

The problem is that a `switch` runs:

1. all code after a case passes a check. Which is why the case statement runs all code after the first case.

   ```js
   let arr = [1, 3];

   if( arr.includes(1) === true ) {
     console.log('if 1');
   }
   if( arr.includes(2) === true) {
     console.log('if 2');
   }
   if( arr.includes(3) === true) {
     console.log('if 3');
   }


   switch( true ){
     case arr.includes(1):
       console.log('switch 1');
     case arr.includes(2): 
       console.log('switch 2');
     case arr.includes(3): 
       console.log('switch 3');
   }
   ```

   2. if a switch has breaks in every case, it runs a single case, that passes the test.

```js
let arr = [1, 3];

if( arr.includes(1) === true ) {
  console.log('if 1');
}
if( arr.includes(2) === true) {
  console.log('if 2');
}
if( arr.includes(3) === true) {
  console.log('if 3');
}


switch( true ){
  case arr.includes(1):
    console.log('switch 1');
    break;
  case arr.includes(2): 
    console.log('switch 2');
    break;
  case arr.includes(3): 
    console.log('switch 3');
    break;
}
```

So the question is: **How can I rewrite multiple `if` statements into a single `switch` statement?**

If I can't: **Is there another more elegant syntax than the multiple `if` statements, that makes it apparent that I am making similar comparisons?**

Comment: the first code sample seems what you are after, what is your issue?

Comment: @George Bailey No, I can't. Check the first example. After a `case` is passed the value in the switch it will run all subsequent code in the other `switch`-es regardless if those switches have the same value as the case.

Comment: Yes, that's how `switch` works. So the second one should be what you want. If you don't like the `switch` behaviour without `break`, why do you want to switch to a `switch` then?

Comment: Well, the way `switch` was originally intended, it was only supposed to execute one branch. Even if you managed to hack it into behaving the way you want (which I'm not sure is possible), it would probably be misleading for an outside reader because of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I rewrite multiple if statements into a single switch statement?

You can't, reasonably, if you want multiple cases to match. `switch` can replace `if`/`else`, but not a series of independent `if`s where more than one can match.

> Is there another more elegant syntax than the multiple if statements, that makes it apparent that I am making similar comparisons?

The answer here will tend to be specific to the code you're writing. A couple of options for you:

### Parameterize into a function

Whenever you have code where you're doing the same thing over and over again, parameterize it and put it in a function, then call the function repeatedly with the parameters.

```
function doTheThing(value) {
  if (arr.includes(value)) {
    console.log('xyz ' + value);
  }
}
```

For instance, in your example:

```js
function doTheThing(value) {
  if (arr.includes(value)) {
    console.log('xyz ' + value);
  }
}

let arr = [1, 3];
doTheThing(1);
doTheThing(2);
doTheThing(3);
```

or

```js
let arr = [1, 3];
[1, 2, 3].forEach(value => {
    if (arr.includes(value)) {
        console.log("xyz " + value);
    }
});
```

or combining those:

```js
function doTheThing(value) {
  if (arr.includes(value)) {
    console.log('xyz ' + value);
  }
}

let arr = [1, 3];
[1, 2, 3].forEach(doTheThing);
```

### Lookup table with actions as functions

If you're doing *different* things, one common practice is to have a lookup table of value-to-action, e.g.:

```js
const actionsByValue = {
  1() {
    console.log("This is the thing for #1");
  },
  2() {
    console.log("This is something else for #2");
  },
  3() {
    console.log("Different logic again for #3");
  }
};
const nop = () => { };

let arr = [1, 3];
arr.forEach(value => {
  (actionsByValue[value] || nop)(value);
});
```

That `1() { }` notation may look odd because you don't see method notation with properties with numeric names very often, but it's perfectly valid. In old environments that don't support method notation:

```
const actionsByValue = {
  1: function() {
    console.log("This is the thing for #1");
  },
  2: function() {
    console.log("This is something else for #2");
  },
  3: function() {
    console.log("Different logic again for #3");
  }
};
```

---

Side note: You never need `=== true` with `Array#includes`. It always returns a boolean.

Comment: This answer is a bit deceiving. It works for this example. But the point of having multiple if statements is to perform different actions/functions based on an input value. Because you assumed I wanted to run the same code with a different input value / variable your code works. But if I wanted to run different functions, I would still need the same if statements, which I wanted to simplify, inside the `doTheThing`-function! That said, you did point it out. But I just wanted to emphasize that this approach has a specific use case.

Comment: @RMo: If the logic is markedly different across the cases, see the updated answer.

Comment: The insights in this answer are definitely worth looking at to see some alternate approaches for the same thing. Especially the lookup table is a really interesting approach. (Despite this I will stick to the multiple `if` statements, because I find it easier to read).